# How to store non-primitive datatype in Room persistence library?

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I am unable to add a non-primitive datatype (Book) in Room DB.
Some people suggested to use TypeConverter but i am not being able to use it for my use case.

The following is my entity class:-

```
    @Entity(tableName = "download_table")

public class BookDownload {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;
    private Book bookData;

    public BookDownload(String user, Book book) {
        bookData = book;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Book getBookData() {
        return bookData;
    }
}
```

I get this error at compile time

```
error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
    private Book bookData;
                 ^
```

This is my **Book.java** class:-

```
public class Book extends BookItem {

    private String publisher;
    private String publishedDate;
    private String description;
    private int pageCount;
    private String category;
    private double rating;
    private int no_ratings;
    private String lang;
    private String webReaderLink;
    private String downloadLink;

    public Book(BookItem bookItem) {
        super(bookItem.getBookId(), bookItem.getTitle(), bookItem.getAuthor(), bookItem.getImage());
    }

    public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public void setPublishedDate(String publishedDate) {
        this.publishedDate = publishedDate;
    }
          //More getters and setters....
    }
```

Comment: Make 'Book' your second entity, set there primary key and put this key as a foreign key to your `BookDownload` class instead `Book` object. If you want to get Book as an object you have to add third class (not entity), let's say `BookDownloadWithBook`,  and use one-to-one `Relation` for that. It's a common way.

Comment: @sergiytikhonov can i make Book class an entity like u said if its also used somewhere else (like in an activity or a recyclerview

Comment: Sure you can. Entity is still a class but with additional feature (persistence to db).Though in some cases there could be options. For example if you someday decide to make book category and language as separate classes, it would be better to use separate Book-classes: one for persistence and another for domain logic.

Comment: ok thanks ill try this soon.

Comment: Mark your `bookData` field as @Embeded because it is user-defined pojo and the best way is to embed it in your entity it is like your entity class containig fields `id, publisher, publishedDate, description, pageCount, category...etc` for your reference [read this developer guid](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#nested-objects)   Thank you.